# About signs of solutions of ODE on an interval

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

We consider the following differential equation,
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
x' =1-2x+xy \\
y' = x-xy 
\end{array}\right.
$$
with initial conditions $x(0) = y(0) =0$. Using Cauchy-Lipschitz theorem, it is easy to show that there exists a unique and maximal solution $X = (x,y)$ on an interval $I = (-t_-,t_+)$. I want to show that,
$$ \forall t \in (0,t_+), \; x(t)>0 \text{ and } y(t)>0 $$
By contradiction, if it were not the case then we could find $0<t_0<t_+$ such that $x(t_0)\leq 0$ or $0<t_1<t_+$ such that $y(t_1) \leq 0$. However, I do not know how to proceed from here, I thought of substituting within the system of equations to have information locally. I should be missing simpler arguments, any hint will be welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the first equation. As $x(0)=0$ we have $x'(0)=1$. Thus $x(t) > 0$
on an interval $(0,\varepsilon)$ for some $\varepsilon> 0$. Now assume that $x(t) > 0$ for $t \in (0,t_+)$ is not true. Then $x$ hits $0$ in $(0,t_+)$ somewhere for the first time, that is there is some $t_0 \in (0,t_+)$ such that $x(t_0)=0$ and $x(t) >0$ $(t \in (0,t_0))$. Then
$$
x'(t_0) = \lim_{t \to t_0-} \frac{x(t)-x(t_0)}{t-t_0} \le 0
$$
but $x'(t_0)=1-2x(t_0) +x(t_0)y(t_0)=1 > 0$, a contradiction. Thus $x(t)> 0$ $(t \in (0,t_+))$.

Next, the second equation is (given $x$) a linear equation for $y$, which can be solved by the Duhamel formula:
$$
y(t)=\exp(\int_0^t -x(\sigma)d\sigma) \int_0^t \exp(\int_0^s x(\sigma)d\sigma) x(s) ds.
$$
With $x$ therefore also $y$ is $>0$ on $(0,t_+)$.

Comment: Great answer, thank you, I missed that $x$ has to take off due to the derivative being positive at 0, from this all becomes very clear! I did not know Duhamel's formula could extend like this, that is interesting. I guess we could do the same job with $y$ knowing that $y''(0)=1$. Anyway, thank you again!